# How to print integers using syscall

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I am trying to print single characters to STDOUT using syscalls, however it is giving me a segfault. The following code is part of a larger program which also uses syscall and rdi to print out regular strings. It prints out "I am" and then I want to print 17 for example. Forgive me, I am very new to assembly.

```
movq    $1, %rax            #sysout
movq    $1, %rdi            #stdout
movq    $'1', (%rsi)        #move char 1 to rsi
movq    $1, %rdx            #move counter(length of string) to rdx (next argument of syscall)
syscall                     #syscall (print)

movq    $1, %rax            #sysout
movq    $1, %rdi            #stdout
movq    $'9', (%rsi)        #move char 9 to rsi
movq    $1, %rdx            #move counter(length of string) to rdx (next argument of syscall)
syscall                     #syscall (print)

movq $60, %rax              # system call 60 is sys exit 
movq $0, %rdx               # normal exit: 0
syscall
```

Comment: You have not set `rsi` to anything. Not surprising that it faults.

Comment: So I move 1 to %rsi instead of (%rsi)?

Comment: No, `(%rsi)` is correct but you need to make sure it points to some writable memory where you can store your `'1'`.

Comment: @VetleHjelmtvedt `rsi` needs to contain the address of a buffer to print.  So store `'1'` somewhere in RAM (e.g. on the stack) and let `rsi` point to it.